# How many sets with K elements possible from a sequence (containing repetitive elements)?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Just for curious, I want to find a combinatorics formula for finding total number of sets that can be formed having k elements(or less than or equal to k elements) from a given sequence(having n elements)that need not contain distinct elements(each repetitive element treated distinguishably).

For example, 
 If the sequence is 2 , 3 , 2 , 4    and k=2
  then possible sets having less than or equal to 2 elements are {},{2},{3},{2},{4},{2,3},{2,4},{2,3},{2,4},{3,4}  , i.e , total 10 sets.

Is there any combinatorics result to find that?

Comment: You are forgiving the couple $(2,2)$?

Comment: Yeah, it’s hard to decide why one $\{2\}$ is different from another,  but $\{2,2\}$ is not considered

Comment: Both 2's are treated distinguishably for forming the set , but yes set must contain distinct elements thus {2,2} will not be considered

Comment: Basically two 2's can be considered inside a box(as distinguishable), from which you are allowed to select only one of them at a time.